# ajax before send different behaviour Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I'm loading a gif to display a spinner while loading the content. In firefox everything works fine but in chrome nothing happens..

```
jQuery.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
    },
    complete: function () {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    },
```

....

```
and the css for the spinner

#loading {
display:    none;
position:   fixed;
z-index:    1000;
top:        0;
left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('../img/loading.gif') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
}
```

Any help with this?

Comment: any errors in console or from the AJAX call? can you actually see that AJAX call working in both browsers?

Comment: no errors on Chrome. The content is loaded, but the property display of the loading div is not changed at all

Comment: can you maybe try putting a `console.log()` into the `beforeSend` function to see if it fires at all? maybe Chrome is too fast and I believe you're hiding the loading div once content is on page, so you might not be able to see the change...

Comment: I've done that and the console.log is fired. When looking at "firebug" for chrome, the div loading is not changing the property style..nothing happens, its weird

Comment: I don't think chrome is that fast because I'm loading a lot of content, and sometimes I get this spinner for 3 or 4 secs on FF

Comment: changing async to true actually works on showing the spinner but it breaks my code cuz i need async set to false..

Comment: ah, you have async false? maybe it was worth mentioning it in your question before...